# Excel conditional formating based on the multiple cells and values

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, excel-2010, data-cleaning

I am trying to implement various conditional formatting to a specific data base. Looked for answer around here but can not find anything similar. Might not be possible but it is worth a try.
I am preforming various data cleansing and validation.
Here is the case: (small sample, working with 100k data entries in this particular file)

[image]

Ultimately what I want is the formula that will compare the low-level Description characters after the last "UNDERSCORE" to the characters after last "UNDERSCORE" of the higher level(highlighted).  If it does not match then highlight the cell?

Asking for too much, yes, no, maybe? I am open to any other suggestions on how can I perform various data cleaning and validation!

Thank you!

Comment: What is "low level" and "higher level" ?

Comment: @NetMage Higher level is highlighted.

Comment: @pnuts  data entry error. Should be MTR, those differences is what I am looking for

Comment: @pnuts hopefully? Look up what are the last characters after underscore in the higher level, compare it to the lower level, if not equal- highlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use the last "UNDERSCORE" character, and can't depend on the suffixes being four characters, the formula becomes quite complex. For simplicity's sake, I assumed the higher level is always missing the last five characters of the lower level, if you must go by the last "DASH" character, then this will be a lot longer.

Use this formula to highlight the cells, defining the two names LEVELS and DESCRS to be the two columns:

```
=IFNA(MID(B2,FIND("[]",SUBSTITUTE(B2,"_","[]",LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"_",""))))+1,999)<>MID(INDEX(DESCRS,MATCH(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-5),LEVELS,0),1),FIND("[]",SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(DESCRS,MATCH(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-5),LEVELS,0),1),"_","[]",LEN(INDEX(DESCRS,MATCH(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-5),LEVELS,0),1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(DESCRS,MATCH(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-5),LEVELS,0),1),"_",""))))+1,999),FALSE)
```

This uses a very nice trick with `SUBSTITUTE` to find the last occurrence of a character.

BTW, I would probably write a Perl program to parse the data and find errors.

Comment: `LEVELS` and `DESCR` are names you need to define for the **Level** and **Descr**iption columns so the formula can search and match on them. Or you can substitute the absolute column references for them (like `$A` and `$B`).

Comment: @NetMage Thank you for greet response! However, it is not running any formatting against my data.  The Higher level is always missing last five characters, so that is not the issue. The number of the last characters after "UNDERSCORE" in description however varies, so in that case, would need to look for the underscore and make the comparison the high level.

Comment: Did you set it up as a conditional format against the Description column? Did you define the two names? You can paste as a formula in a cell to the right of a description to see if you get TRUE or FALSE in that cell to verify it works.